# Calc Order sum where Orderline contains product

Tags: sql, sum, sql-server-2012

I got this Sql Query

```
declare @ProductNo int

set @ProductNo = 123

select o.OrderNo, OrderDate, ol.Amount
from OrderLine ol
inner join [Order] o on ol.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
where ol.ProductNo = @ProductNo
```

Now my question is, that I would like to return a sum for each Order.
I tryid changing my query to

```
select o.OrderNo, OrderDate, ol.Amount,(select sum(ol.Amount * ol.UnitPrice) as OrderTotal from OrderLine oll where oll.OrderNo = o.OrderNo)
    from OrderLine ol
    inner join [Order] o on ol.OrderNo = o.OrderNo
    where ol.ProductNo = @ProductNo
```

But that's not running, so I'm hoping someone could help me complete my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sub-select you're referring to `ol.Amount * ol.UnitPrice`, but your `OrderLine` table is called `oll` in the sub-query, so the following should do:

```
select o.OrderNo, OrderDate, ol.Amount,(select sum(oll.Amount * oll.UnitPrice) from OrderLine oll where oll.OrderNo = o.OrderNo) as OrderTotal
....
```